# seeing error register for model in model_or_iterable: TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-models

I have following models  in

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text[:50]


POWER_CHOICES= (('O', 'ON'),
                ('F','OFF')
        )

STATE_CHOICES =(('AV','Available'),
               ('U','In Use '),
               ('NU','Do Not Use')                
       )

class Device(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50 )

   ipaddress=models.ForeignKey('Ipaddress', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

   devicetype= models.ForeignKey('DeviceType', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   model= models.ForeignKey('DeviceModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   description= models.TextField(max_length=400)
   location= models.ForeignKey('Location', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   group= models.ForeignKey('DeviceGroup', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   managment= models.CharField(max_length=100)
   power= models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=POWER_CHOICES)
   offtime= models.CharField(max_length=30)
   state= models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
   user= models.CharField(max_length=100)
#   department= models.ForeignKey('Department',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   comments= models.CharField(max_length=200)

   def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name[:50]

class DeviceType(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name[:50]

class DeviceModel(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name[:50]

class Ipaddress(models.Model):
    address=models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    owner=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    loation=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    note =models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.address[:50]

class Department:
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name[:50] 


class DeviceGroup:
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name[:50] 

class Location:
    description= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description[:50]
```

My admin page looks like as below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from pages.models import Post, Device, DeviceType, DeviceModel, Ipaddress, DeviceGroup, Location

admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Device)
admin.site.register(DeviceType)
admin.site.register(DeviceModel)
admin.site.register(Ipaddress)
#admin.site.register(Department)
admin.site.register(DeviceGroup)
admin.site.register(Location)
```

I am seeing following error  and not sure what causing this error.
Can someone please give me some idea. please

```
...
...
File "C:\Users\mohiuddin_rana\labmcproject\pages\admin.py", line 10, in <module>
    admin.site.register(DeviceGroup)
  File "C:\Users\mohiuddin_rana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 102, in register
    for model in model_or_iterable:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Your `DeviceGroup` (and others) do *not* subclass `Model`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For some of your models, you forgot to subclass it from `models.Model`:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name[:50] 


class DeviceGroup(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name[:50] 

class Location(models.Model):
    description= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description[:50]
```

This change will also result in some migrations, since up till now, Django (probably) did not understand that these classes were actually models, and therefore did *not* construct database equivalents.

Django expects a model when you register it to the `admin.site` variable, but the check fails. As a "fallback" mechanism, it checks if you perhaps have provided an iterable of models, but this again fails, since it is just a "vanilla" class.

This behavior can be confirmed when we check the [source code of the `register(..)` function [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L85):

> ```
> def register(self, model_or_iterable, admin_class=None, **options):
>
>     # ...
>
>     admin_class = admin_class or ModelAdmin
>     if isinstance(model_or_iterable, ModelBase):
>         model_or_iterable = [model_or_iterable]
>     for model in model_or_iterable:
>         # ...
>         pass
> ```

(I removed some parts to make the semantics more clear).

As you can see, it checks if the `model_or_iterable` you pass is a model. If that is the case, it wraps it in a list, otherwise it assumes it is an iterable, and aims to iterate over it.

> **Note**: it looks like you use `__unicode__`, but use Python-3.x at the same time. `__unicode__` has, to the best of my knowledge, no meaning anymore in the Python-3.x data model. You should use `__str__` instead.

Comment: I've seen you mention "vanilla" class before, I did a (quick) search and couldn't find what you are refering to. Well, I find http://django-vanilla-views.org/ but I guess this is not what you are refering to. Would you point where or how to look for it? Thanks!

Comment: @guillermochamorro: vanilla is meant as "boring"/"average"/"casual". In English it is frequently used to say something is not special. Just like for example a "default" milkshake is typically vanilla :).

Comment: @guillermochamorro: see here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451476/history-of-the-idiomatic-usage-of-vanilla

Answer (score 2):

```
class Department(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name[:50] 


class DeviceGroup(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name[:50]
```

include (models.Model) in all your class its compulsory